# using Scanner to read a file

Tags: java, regex

I found the following useful in the past for reading in text files:

```
new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

However I came across a file today that was only partially read in with this syntax. I'm not sure what makes this file special, it's just a .jsp

I found the below worked in this instance but I'd like to know why the previous method didn't work.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
String text = in.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
```

Comment: What size was the jsp file?  Might there be some kind of special character in it that woulds cause issues?  From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) the difference seems to be file vs. stream input.

Comment: next() method returns the next token. I guess the first encounter of next - pulled the file upto the token and it pulled partially.

Answer (score 0):

Save the jsp file as .txt and try to read it using your first method. if it works i feel size can be the issue.